# How to maintain "gutter space" between "responsive" grid divs when they collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the newest twitter bootstrap to construct a responsive grid website.  i have three divs across a responsive grid like so:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span4">...</div>
 <div class="span4">...</div>
 <div class="span4">...</div>
</div>
```

...and this works as intended via the bootsrap documentation. However I have a separate background color on these divs from the html body background color, and when i drag the browser window to a smaller width to "collapse" the divs to show on top of each other, the gutter space between them disappears (creating a look of one big div versus three separate ones) is there anything i can do to create some gutter space between the divs when the width gets small enough to cause them to stack vertically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options...

(1) You could define a class and apply it to any divs you want to have a bottom margin.

**In your application.css (or similar):**

`.mb10 {margin-bottom:10px;}`

**In your html page:**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span4 mb10">....</div>
   <div class="span4 mb10">....</div>
   <div class="span4 mb10">....</div>
</div>
```

**OR**

(2) You could make sure you wrap your `div.span4` content in `<p></p>` tags.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span4"><p>....</p></div>
   <div class="span4"><p>....</p></div>
   <div class="span4"><p>....</p></div>
</div>
```

From the Bootstrap - Typography section:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography

> In addition,
>   `<p>` (paragraphs) receive a bottom margin of half their line-height
>   (10px by default).

Comment: thank you very much! I opted for the "class" option, however i will try to keep everything you shared in mind as i move forward.

Comment: You bet. Good luck with your site!